# How to make CRM include line numbers in stack trace when custom plugin throws?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I grabbed my symbols file (let's call it `PLUGIN.PDB`) file and copied it on the server, under

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Server\bin\assembly

I then registered the plugin:

- Isolation: **Sandbox**
- Location: **Database**

But the stack trace **does not** include line numbers.

I wondered if I misplaced the PDB file and/or something was amiss, I unregistered the DLL, copied it (let's call it `PLUGIN.DLL`) and re-registered it:

- Isolation: **None**
- Location: **Disk**

Lo and behold, I got line numbers in the stack trace.

Am I doing something wrong / missing something ? The Plugin Registration Tool states that placing the PDB in the \server\bin\assembly folder should do, and scavenging Google seems to confirm that info.

The plugin is a C# Class Library, FW 4.0 (the Developer Toolkit isn't involved).

Comment: Any chance that you happened to build it in release mode?

Comment: After deploying the plugin to the Database in Sandbox mode and copying the PDB file to the bin\assembly folder I would suggest an IISRESET and a restart of the Sandbox service.

Comment: I verified and it was built in Debug mode, going to give a shot at IISRESET-ing